# Compiler error "missing ';' before 'type'" and unsure why

Tags: c

I get the error `error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'type'` during compilation, on the line where I declare `char *buf` in the following code, and I can't figure out why. I'm running Visual Studio 2012. It apparently compiles just fine in gcc. Is there some setting in VS that I need to change in order to get this to compile, or a code modification I can make?

The only thing I am trying to do right now is create a char array with the same size as my file `input.txt`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int get_file_size(FILE *inputfile);

int main()
{
    FILE *inputfile;
    int filesize;
    char filename[FILENAME_MAX];

    inputfile = fopen("input.txt","r");
    filesize = get_file_size(inputfile);
    char *buf = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*filesize);
    fclose(inputfile);

    return 0;
}

int get_file_size(FILE *inputfile)
{
    int size;

    inputfile = fopen("input.txt","r");
    fseek(inputfile,0,SEEK_END);
    size = ftell(inputfile);
    fclose(inputfile);

    return size;
}
```

Comment: What compiler are you using? This compiles fine with `gcc` and no special options. Btw, your `get_file_size` reopens the input file after you already opened it and then closes it. Then upon your return, the main program closes it again.

Comment: It may be a stray unprintable character in the file.  Trim away blanks at the ends of your lines in that area.  Also, try commenting out parts to see what changes.  And make sure there's no `#define` for `char` or some such lurking somewhere.

Comment: What n.m. flagged: VS does not support C99, so a declaration such as  `char* buf` in the middle of the function in C code is invalid.

Comment: OK, that dupe reference seems likely -- brain dead compiler that can't handle an initializing declaration.

Comment: Thank you. Issue resolved by declaring char *buf with my other declarations at the beginning of main.

Comment: @HotLicks: It's not a about a "brain dead compiler", it's about a compiler which meets an old specification.

Comment: Its because your source file has a `.c` extension, and compiles under C's rules.  If it had a `.cpp` extension, it would compile as C++, and work fine.

Comment: @abelenky: Perhaps, but as C++ code it would be poor style. C and C++ are two different languages; there's nothing wrong with choosing to use C rather than C++.

Comment: The cast on the result of `malloc` is unneeded and ill-advised. That line is better written as `char *buf = malloc(filesize);` (note that `sizeof (char)` is 1 by definition). Also, passing `inputfile` as an argument to `get_file_size` is pointless, since the function doesn't use the value that was passed in (presumably it should).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

VS does not support C99, so all of your variable declarations must be at the top of the current scope.  For you, that means the top of the function.